# Symbols for Volt and voltage

Tags: potential, voltage, conventions, notation, si-units

The symbols for Volt and for voltage are both $V$. Usually, the meaning of $V$ is clear enough from context to avoid confusion. However, I find a bit odd when both $V$ appear in the same formula. For example:

$$V=I \cdot R={10A} \cdot {5 \Omega}=50V$$

Is there an international standard how to write that more clearly?

I'm looking for a way that could be easily used in LaTex or Mathjax, but other information about what the usual notation is will also be welcomed.

Comment: Units are not italicised. Symbols for quantities are. So we could write $V$=12 V, for example

Comment: Common practice is to use italic letters for physical quantities (like voltage) and upright letters for units (like Volt).
For example: $V=10\text{ V}$. In MathJax you can achieve this by `$V=10\text{ V}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SI brochure](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf), which defines the International System of Units and makes recommendations about its usage, specifies that (§5.4.1, emphasis mine)

> Symbols for quantities are generally single letters set in an *italic font*

and that

> Unit symbols are printed in *upright type* regardless of the type used in the surrounding text.

Therefore, your example should become

$$V =IR = 10\,\mathrm{A}\times 5\,\Omega= 50\,\mathrm{V}$$

Note also another change in the above, I've used a cross for the product of the two quantity values instead of the centred dot. In fact (§5.4.6),

> When multiplying the value of quantities either a multiplication sign
> × or brackets should be used, not a half-high (centred) dot. When
> multiplying numbers only the multiplication sign × should be used.

You can find other information on how to write values in different contexts and a complete list of references about quantities, units and quantity calculus in [this answer of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28918/20058) on Academia SE. And if you use $\LaTeX$, there is the package [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) which handles the formatting of quantities and units according to the SI brochure in an easy way.

Finally, note also that quantity names like volt, ampere etc. should start with a lower case initial (e.g. ampere is the unit, Ampère is the scientist).